# Show that the following are not subspaces of R^m

Tags: linear-algebra

Can I get some guidance on this question?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I reckon the zero vector is always in a vector subspace.

Comment: @Jenny Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Recall that by definition the zero vector must belong to any subspace.

Comment: What does it mean by the set of all vectors whose first component is 2? Does it mean (2,1), (2,0), (2,-1) etc?

Comment: For example v=(2,0,0,0,...) and thus the zero vector is not in the subset.

Comment: @Jenny In general to check that a subset is a subspace we need to verify 3 definition properties, here it suffices to refer to the property that $\vec 0\in W$ for any subspace.

Answer (score 1):

A subspace must contain the sum of two vectors belonging to it, but the sum of two vectors of the type in part (a) cannot have 2 as a first component.

0 must belong to any subspace of a vector space.

As for three, if the sum of the components of vector $v$ and the sum of components of vector $w$ both are 1, the sum of the components of vector $v+w$ is not 1.

Try to get more acquainted with the definitions.

Comment: So would part (a) be something like this: let u=(2,1) and v=(2,0) so u+v= (4,1) which is not a subspace since the first component is not 2?

Comment: Something like: this subset cannot be a subspace because taking u and v like you just did, it is clear their sum doesn't belong to it, because of the perfectly correct calculation you made, so it cannot be a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector space $V$ and its subspace $W$, considering any $v\in V, w\in W$:

1. First, notice that $0\cdot v=\mathbf{0_V}$, which can be proved:
   $0\cdot v+ 0\cdot v=_{\textrm{by axiom 8}} (0+0)\cdot v=0\cdot v$, which means $0\cdot v=\mathbf{0_V}$ by cancellation law, which can also be proved using those axioms.
2. Second, notice that $0\cdot w=\mathbf{0_V}$, since $W$ is just a subset of $V$, so $w\in W$ also means $w\in V$, by (1.) we have this equality hold.
3. Finally, since $w+\mathbf{0_W}=w$, but for the same reason $w\in V$, so $w+\mathbf{0_V}=w.$ by cancellation law, we have that $\mathbf{0_W}=\mathbf{0_V}=_{\textrm{as a shorthand}}\mathbf{0}$.

So this is the story of why anyone here tell you to check whether $\mathbf{0}$, which means $\mathbf{0_V}$, is in the subspace under the discussion.

Anyway, don't be discouraged by the downvotes. But try to think about why people don't consider it a good question!